# Pandas (Python) - Segment Data into Timeframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of DateTime (index) and a sampling of power usage:

```
DateTime          Usage
01-Jan-17 12am    10
01-Jan-17 3am     5
01-Jan-17 6am     15
01-Jan-17 9am     40
01-Jan-17 12pm    60
01-Jan-17 3pm     62
01-Jan-17 6pm     45
01-Jan-17 9pm     18
02-Jan-17 12am    11
02-Jan-17 3am     4
02-Jan-17 6am     17
02-Jan-17 9am     37
02-Jan-17 12pm    64
02-Jan-17 3pm     68
02-Jan-17 6pm     41
02-Jan-17 9pm     16
```

In reality, this series is much longer.   I am trying to compare day-over-day time periods, such that I can look at the daily-seasonality of the time series.   Is there a way in panda's to split the data such that you can compare these time series?  I'd imagine the resulting DataFrame would look something like:

```
Time    1-Jan   2-Jan
12am    10      11
3am     5       4
6am     15      17
9am     40      37
12pm    60      64
3pm     62      68
6pm     45      41
9pm     18      16
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `DateTime` as `str` data type, you can split it into `Date` and `Time` and then pivot it:

```
df[['Date', 'Time']] = df.DateTime.str.split(" ", expand=True)
df1 = df.pivot("Time", "Date", "Usage").reset_index()
```

[image]

---

How to sort the `Time` column? It's actually not so straight forward, to do this, we need to extract some columns from the Time, the hour, the PM/AM indicator as well as if the hour is 12, as 12 should be placed above all other hours:

```
# use regex to extract Hour (numeric part of Time) and AM/PM indicator
hourInd = df1.Time.str.extract("(?P<Hour>\d+)(?P<Ind>[pa]m)", expand=True)

# convert the hour column to integer and create another column to check if hour is 12
# then sort by AM/PM indicator, IsTwelve and Hour and get the index to reorder the original 
# data frame
df1.loc[(hourInd.assign(Hour = hourInd.Hour.astype(int), IsTwelve = hourInd.Hour != "12")
         .sort_values(["Ind", "IsTwelve", "Hour"]).index)]
```

[image]